# Check color value of pixel on screen

Tags: python, colors, mouse

I'm making a bot that automatically clicks if the mouse is *not* over a specific color. I have everything from positioning to clicking, but I do not know how I can check if the pixel the mouse is over is a specific color. I currently use `mouse` and `keyboard`, and google hasn't given me the results fitting for my situation.

It is also not an image, but live on the screen.

It should look something like this:

```
colorUnderMouse = getColorUnderMouse()
if colorUnderMouse == "FF00FF":
  mouse.click('left')
else:
  mouse.move(10, 0, absolute=False, duration=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pyautogui`:

```
import pyautogui

def getColorUnderMouse():
    x, y= pyautogui.position()
    pixel = pyautogui.screenshot(
        region=(
            x, y, 1, 1
        )
    )
    return pixel.getcolors()
```